# Большой размер типов данных. Python

Tags: python-3.x, архитектура, память, дизайн-языка

**Общий вопрос:**

Почему в Python объекты "привычных" типов данных столько весят?

```py
>>> sys.getsizeof(int())
12
>>> sys.getsizeof(bool())
12
>>> sys.getsizeof(str())
25
>>> sys.getsizeof("")
25
>>> sys.getsizeof(" ")
26
>>> sys.getsizeof(float())
16
```

То есть интересует какие именно элементы класса занимают лишнюю память.

**Конкретные вопросы:**

1. Где находятся конструкторы классов `int`, `str`, `bool`... (директория/файл)?
2. В чем смысл `bool`, если он весит столько же, сколько и `int`? При проверке условия `if cond: ...` после приведения типов `type(cond)` == `bool` или `int`?

*PS Возможно вопросы туповаты, но уж очень любопытно) Быть может кто-то знает секреты ресурсоемкой питоновской магии.*

Comment: А в каком языке (ну кроме Java), вы ещё сможете возвести несколько миллиардов в милионные степени?

Comment: Boolean Objects¶.
Booleans in Python are implemented as a subclass of integers. похоже размеры такие изза того что все они объекты, а не строчка в памяти

Comment: @nightflash Я понимаю, что область значений int в Python гораздо больше, чем просто integer на 4 байта, но мне интересно что именно занимает лишнюю память в объекте. Если не int, то bool или char. Что находится в 25 байтах любой питоновской строки, если каждый char занимает ровно 1 байт?

Comment: @SmellyNS   https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyObject

Comment: Boolean и в си интегер. Связанно это с выравниванием памяти

Comment: @Интик Спасибо за комментарий, но то что они являются объектами классов я понимаю, потому так их и называю в вопросе. По указанной ссылке я не смог найти информации о местонахождении исходников PyObject или описания архитектуры каждого объекта

Comment: @eri Спасибо, почитал про выравнивание памяти. Если я всё правильно понял, это может касаться работы процессов на уровне оси (деление на машинные слова по 4 байта) и на уровне конкретного языка (например выравнивание элементов структуры в Си). Всё же не понятно, почему при машинном слове 4 байта объекты разных классов весят одинаково, хотя имеют разную область допустимых значений

Comment: @SmellyNS, boolean - подтип int (`issubclass(bool, int) == True`). По сути это тот же int, на который наложены ограничения допустимых значений.

Comment: @insolor То есть нет никакой разницы в использовании bool и int? Допустим, я могу завести флаг bool (True/False) или флаг int (1/0) и совать его потом в `if`. В первом случае будет хотя бы немного оптимальнее?

Comment: Теоретически флаг bool будет оптимальнее, потому что int потом еще будет неявно приводиться к bool при использовании его в качестве условия if. Но чтобы сказать точнее, как все работает - нужно смотреть сишные исходники Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

12 байт от переменной занимает [структура PyVarObject](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2fbc57af851814df567fb51054cb6f6a399f814a/Include/object.h#L109). Но в зависимости от типа там может быть ещё куча указателей.

int в Питоне имеет динамический размер, питон подбирает что использовать (int32,int64) в зависимости от величины

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(9223372036854775807)
36
>>> sys.getsizeof(1)
28
>>> sys.getsizeof(0)
24
```

bool занимает 4 байта так как это наследования типа из Си. Плюс [PyTypeObject](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2fbc57af851814df567fb51054cb6f6a399f814a/Include/boolobject.h#L10).

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(True)
28
```

Также как и в Си boolean это int.

```
>>> True==1
True
>>> True+True
2
>>>
```

Не char а int потому, что из-за выравнивания памяти в языке и в процессоре int работает быстрее других типов.

У меня 64битная ОС, поэтому указатели 8 байтные (24 вместо 12).

Comment: Это си, тут нет конструктора, тут структура с пачкой указателей. исходники https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Include/object.h

Comment: Да, это ответ, огромное спасибо) побежал изучать

Comment: Там правда есть макросы, такие как PyAPI_DATA. Их можно раскрыть через `gcc -E`